# Input name like <input type="hidden" name="questionId[]" value="<%=question.id%>" > is not working in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to make mcq system . it was working  but last couple of days radio buttons is not working
<% for(question of ContestQuestionSet) {%>

```
                          <tr class="table-warning ">
                            <th><%=i%>. <%- question.question.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br/>')%></th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr class="table-success">
                            <th><span class="bd-highlight mr-2">A)</span><input class="mr-2" type="radio" name="answer[<%=question.id%>]" value="A"><%=question.option1%></th>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr class="table-success">
                            <th><span class="bd-highlight mr-2">B)</span><input class="mr-2" type="radio" name="answer[<%=question.id%>]" value="B"><%=question.option2%></th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr class="table-success">
                            <th><span class="bd-highlight mr-2">C)</span><input class="mr-2" type="radio" name="answer[<%=question.id%>]" value="C"><%=question.option3%></th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr class="table-success ">
                            <th><span class="bd-highlight mr-2">D)</span><input class="mr-2" type="radio" name="answer[<%=question.id%>]" value="D"><%=question.option4%></th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr class="table-primary ">
                            <th><span class="bd-highlight mr-2">E)</span><input class="mr-2" type="radio"  name="answer[<%=question.id%>]" value="E" checked>Avoid this question</th>
                          </tr>
                          <input type="hidden" name="questionId[]" value="<%=question.id%>" >
                          

                        </table>
                        <%i++; }%>
                          <%}%>
```

Comment: Please share the details on what you mean by not working. Are you getting errors or no outuput at all?

Comment: quesitionIn is undefined